# Style Facebook Login Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Facebook SDK supply a LoginButton widget for Login. If I change the LoginButton background or custom it by replacing the image, will it allowed? If it violate the Facebook Policy？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the appearence of Social Plugins is not allowed (and not possible anyway), but you can use your own Login Button with the [`FB.login`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login) function of the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Style Login Button in Android is possible and I have got it. I just want to know the Policy. Thanks for your reply.